# How to use webpack5 if react-scripts is installing webpack4 by itself?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-scripts

react-scripts v4.0.3 installs webpack4.44.2 while doing npm i

I want it use webpack5 in my project if I install it explicitly, react gives dependency tree error.

How can I use webpack5 then?

Comment: you need to eject or wait for they upgrades webpack to v5

Comment: I've not used it in a while but you may be able [to do something with Rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts) without ejecting.